# Find the absolute extrema of the function $f(x)=x^2-2x-2$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Find the absolute extrema of the function $f(x)=x^2-2x-2$ on $[0,1]$

---

To find a the extrema of a continuous function $f$ on a closed interval $[a,b]$, use the following steps:

1) Find the critical numbers of $f$ on the open interval $(a,b)$.

2) Evaluate $f$ at each of its critical numbers in $(a,b)$

3) Evaluate $f$ at the endpoints, $a$ and $b$

4) The least of these values is the absolute minimum, the greatest of these is the maximum.

---

Solution:

Since our function is continuous on $[0,1]$, we can just follow the above steps to find the absolute maximum and absolute minimum.

Let's find the critical numbers by solving $f'(x)=0$:

$f'(x)=2x-2=0$

$\rightarrow x=1$

And so all the points where absolute extrema could happen are when $x=1$ and then the boundary points, which are $x=0$ and $x=1$. So in this case, the value of $x$ such that $f'(x)=0$ was already one of our boundary points! So the values we need to evalute are $f(0)$ and $f(1)$:

$f(0)= 0^2 -2(0)-2=-2$

$f(1)= 1^2 -2(1)-2 =-3$

So our absolute maximum is $(0,-2)$ and our absolute minimum is $(1,-3)$

Comment: Yep.  And just plot the function to confirm.

Comment: Must you use a calculus related solution?  $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ has its optimal value at $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No calculus is needed if you remember how to complete the square: $f(x)=x^2-2x-2=(x-1)^2-3$.

Thus the minimum is at $x=1$ and the max at $x=0$.